# Default Alert for Social View is not shown in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, ios7

I implemented the Social framework in my app to post on facebook. It works fine.

But if there is `no account in settings`, then the **Defalut alert** is not come in `IOS 7`.

In IOS 6, it will come as follow.

[image]

**Is this default Problem in ios 7?**

**My code is as follow:**

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.appcoda.com"]];
    [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconTemp.png"]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: remove the if statement and it will work.

Comment: @Shabirjan, Let me try

Comment: @Shabirjan, good It will work.

Comment: good to hear so now it is working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work in iOS 7, just remove the following line from your code and it will work fine.

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
```